Is a priori (non-empirical-evidence-based) mathematical knowledge possible under reductive physicalism?
Suppose, for the sake of argument, that reductive physicalism is true. Then, thoughts are nothing but physical brain states. In particular, mathematical thoughts are nothing but physical brain states. Under these conditions, would it be possible to have a priori mathematical knowledge, that is, knowledge about mathematical truths without resort to experience/empirical evidence?

Feels like this might ultimately be semantics on the definition of a priori. Obviously there's some degree of math that appears hardwired in animals brains (many animals can count enough to choose the higher number, e.g.). Is that knowledge a priori (it is known without any reference to experience or observation) or a posterori (it is only known because of facts about the world e.g. brain configuration)

Anyways I worry that the domain of possible responses here are essentially the same as with the previous question. e.g. I would paste my analytic/synthetic answer, and any answer here can also be a good answer to "how can we understand math without empirical reference"

What do you consider a mathematical truth to be? If I mathematical truth is a valid deduction from an axiom system, I don't see how anyone can have knowledge about it being so, without actually having the proof at hand.

Now, if you consider knowledge about a truth, to include intuitions- I don't see how you have intuotions about a particular set of axioms, without working with them first.

@user80226 Your link to wikipedia defines “Reductive physicalism is the view that mental states are both nothing over and above physical states and reducible to physical states.” Please add your definition of “mental state”, and clarify how you imagine that mental states “reduce” to physical states. - Not till then we know the presuppositions of your question. Before it makes no sense to search for an answer.

It's certainly theoretically possible to have a priori beliefs or mental abilities, because those things would also be brain states, and there's plenty of brain development prior to birth, and that could put some beliefs in place (although, practically speaking, it seems more that it may bias us to certain types of thinking, which may lead to being more inclined towards certain beliefs).
* If you were to extend "a priori" to prior to conception, then the answer is arguably: no, we can't have beliefs, because you can't believe anything if you don't exist yet. Although "you" are encoded to a significant degree within the genes of your parents, and those were around before you were conceived, so that's some idea of that.
One might also consider that the things we're taught growing up, from before we're able to say our first word, significantly influences what we believe and how we think later in life. It's debatable whether (at least some of) that could be classified as "a priori".
As for a priori knowledge, I'm not sure that makes sense for ANY worldview. Although there is a question of what knowledge is. Under the common definition of "justified true belief", it doesn't seem possible, as justification is a process that you'd need to go through (although that's also something one can say a lot about). It doesn't seem to make sense to say you can just start with an already-justified belief. Although you can certainly start with a belief, and then later justify it. Or you may start with a true belief, in any worldview where you can start with beliefs (even if you may not be justified in thinking it's true, at that point).

I haven't mentioned maths because I don't see much that would be specific to that.
Our brains may be wired so as to allow understand that putting one thing next to another thing makes for two of those things (I'd say that's more of an ability, a potential, rather than a belief, although it's also possible for a brain to start off with that as a belief). But the concept of "two" is also to some extent an abstract object that humans conceived of and ascribed to collections of things in the real world. We can also then go out into the world and put one thing next to another thing and see that there are now two things, to turn that into a belief and into knowledge.

Babies can show surprise when they see things that shouldn't be physically possible (in experiments where appearance is manipulated). But perhaps they have already seen enough by then to have a basic sense of ordinary physics.

Given that pure mathematics is nothing but a set of rules for manipulating symbols, the assumptions baked into those rules are not directly dependent upon physical reality.
Of course we have chosen those assumptions, and those rules, to model the reality we find ourselves in, and they have turned out to be a remarkably successful model, partly because we have refined them as necessary to handle additional cases. For example, while it is true that the angles of a triangle on a plane add to 180°, that knowledge has to be adjusted when the triangle is not on a flat surface. (Note that this applies even when the surface is described by a formula rather than being connected to reality.)
Trying to talk about the physicality or non-physicality of mathematics, it seems to me, simply misses the point. Math can be used as a model of the physical world, but technically "exists" in the noosphere. Of course whether the noosphere is itself based in the physical world depends on how you define physical.

Why Wouldn't the Laws of Thought be directly dependent on physical reality. They were generated by brains, which are constituents of reality. Can reality "create" things, which are not part of reality?

Proofs, in standard mathematics, can be entirely embeded into finite strings of 1's and 0's. So, mathematical truth ( in terms of proofs) can be reduced to the ability for a computer to print certain sequences of  0's and 1's, following particular rules, which themselbes encodable as a sequence of 0's & 1's, ( so on/off states )  I don't see how that's not a feature of reality. Now, there are more esoteric areas of math, without such a reduction. But, Standard Mathematics can be reduced in this way.

@MichaelCarey As it happens I agree that thought is a function of the brain, but not everyone is convinced yet and it's orthogonal to my point. Lots of other places for that discussion; not here please.
